# SSRS Call a second report with params in current report

Tags: reporting-services

I have read of linked reports where the user has to click on an element in a report to call for the next one.  I do NOT WANT any user reaction required.

My ERP system makes a BOL report.  That report has all the params I need to pass to a second report the Certificate of Analysis.

To me a subreport is on the same report itself.  What is the term for this second report?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

SSRS offer drillthrough reports, which sound like what you're after.

[Drillthrough Reports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519554.aspx)

> A drillthrough report is a report that a user opens by clicking a link
>   within another report.

To set one up, right click on a report element and set **Action** -> **Go To Report** and set it to the required drillthrough report.

You can set up the drillthrough report to accept parameters or fields from a Dataset in the parent report as required.